# Android studio messing up my code when using with flutter

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter

I am facing a weird problem that doesn't always happens, which is that the code in a certain page is getting mixed up with another but somehow the application is working normal and when i use version control, everything getting pushed is normal.

For example, this is what i am seeing when i open a file which contains a class called NewOrder

[image]

And here is the real code that i just pulled from bitbucket

[image]

This is getting so irritating since its happening very often, i then have to copy the code from my git after pulling and paste it in android studio... 
This isn't the only file that got messed up, it actually happened to 5-6 more.

Comment: FYI:
However, this is a genuine issue. It's not related to Flutter or git. I saw the same issue in A Pure `Android` Project.

Comment: It's really weird that this problem isn't tackled yet, i also recall it happening to me a year back when i was working on android..

Comment: Exactly, that's what I felt as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue before. 
Do the following:

1. Close the Current project and then select the "Invalidate cache" option from the 'File' menu.
2. Delete `.AndroidStudio3.X` directories (for windows, It is in C:\Users\UserName)
3. Open the Project again in android studio

Answer (score 0):

select the "Invalidate caches/Restart" option from the 'File' menu then select "Invalidate and Restart" and thats it. Otherwise you can refer local history for code copying by right click select "Local History -> show history"

[image]